# How to trigger onload in addition to other triggers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

How can I make this trigger when the page is loaded:

```
$(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
});
```

So far I tried this:

```
$(window).on('ready scroll resize', function() {
});
```

and this:

```
$(window).on('load scroll resize', function() {
});
```

Seems like such a simple thing and it should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ] )
```

> **events** - An object in which the string keys represent one or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, and the values
>   represent a handler function to be called for the event(s).

Comment: I see, so I guess I have to trigger onload separately  then?

Comment: I think `scroll` and `resize` handling has no sense until window loaded. Just imagine while window is loading it can change its dimensions many times. So `.on('load',..` should be outer function. or separate